# Ruby - Assign variable and return if found in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for a neater way to assign a variable and return if the value is found in the DB in a controller before_action method that does not require multiple DB calls:

```
if Plan.exists?(plan)
  @plan = Plan.find(plan)
  return
end
logger.error "User selected invalid plan."
redirect_to plan_path, warning: "Invalid plan selected!"
```

Would this be an appropriate place to use a rescue? E.g:

```
begin
  @plan = Plan.find(plan)
rescue
  logger.error "User selected invalid plan."
  redirect_to plan_path, warning: "Invalid plan selected!"
end
```

It feels wrong... what is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a best approach I think. It's a matter of taste. I usually do something like your latter way in a Rails 5 API. Something like

```
def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  render json: { error: "Book not found" }
end
```

And if everything goes fine I have a view for the happy path

Answer (score 1):

[Some](http://mensfeld.pl/2015/03/exceptions-should-not-be-expected-stop-using-them-for-control-flow-or-any-other-logic-handling-in-ruby/) consider it an anti-pattern to use exceptions for flow control. Personally, I tend to agree. But, I suppose it is a matter of style and preference.

How about something like:

```
  def foo_before_action
    unless @plan = Plan.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to plan_path, warning: "Invalid plan selected!"
    end
  end
```

Or perhaps as a one-liner:

```
  def foo_before_action
    redirect_to plan_path, warning: "Invalid plan selected!" unless @plan = Plan.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
```

The former is, perhaps, a bit more readable.

Comment: Only concern is that Rubocop will complain about use of single = in an if statement